# LazyVStack not lazy if not within a ScrollView or List?

Tags: swiftui

It seems that LazyVStack is only "lazy" when within a ScrollView or List?

Code below:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        makeBody()
    }
    
    private func makeBody() -> some View {
        // ScrollView { // uncomment to see difference
        ContainerView { //
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) {
                    WrappedText(s: String($0))
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    struct WrappedText: View {
        var s: String

        var body: some View {
            makeBody()
        }
        
        private func makeBody() -> some View {
            print("Wrapped text body: \(s)") // this is called for all texts during initialisation (if not in a ScrollView / List)
            return Text(String(s))
        }
    }
}

struct ContainerView<Content: View>: View {

    let content: Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        return self.content
    }
}
```

I'm currently experimenting with creating a pure SwiftUI ScrollView, and am stuck on this.

I've tried using `.clipped()` and setting the `.frame` on `ContainerView` and `LazyVStack`. Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe this will help you: "By default, SwiftUI’s VStack and HStack load all their contents up front, which is likely to be slow if you use them inside a scroll view. If you want to load content lazily – i.e., only when it scrolls into view, you should use LazyVStack and LazyHStack as appropriate."   https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-lazy-load-views-using-lazyvstack-and-lazyhstack

Comment: It seems like, LazyXStack views also "load its whole content" upfront, unless they are embedded in a ScrollView. This also happens when the view containing the Lazy view has its frame explicitly set and the Lazy view's content exceeds this frame by any margin. "loading upfront" means, actually, that the init function of the content views will be called when the Lazy view will be initialised. So, we need a ScrollView which embeds the Lazy view to make it lazy.

Comment: I think that's right. I have a lazyvstack that's quite far down the group hierarchy from the scrollview and it doesn't load lazy. it needs to be 1 or 2 levels down forms he scrollview