# SwiftUI, Can CustomScrollView (made by UIViewControllerRepresentable) takes LazyVStack?

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

Im using custom scrollview with UIViewControllerRepresentable and works fine but when I using with LazyVStack it doesn't work that I expected.

LazyVStack doesn't create items until it needs to render them onscreen But when I use this with custom scrollview, it draws at once.

So when I do this,

```
   ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(0...10000, id:\.self) {
                        Text(String($0))
                    }
                }
   }
```

It works well, 10,000 items are shows well without lagging.

But when I do this with my custom scrollView

```
  CustomScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(0...10000, id:\.self) {
                        Text(String($0))
                    }
                }
  }
```

It comsumes memory as I expected.

Can't I using this with custom scrollView?

Comment: why you should use CustomScrollView, which thing in scrolling is deferent that you what custom one?

Comment: Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65726652/lazyvstack-not-lazy-if-not-within-a-scrollview-or-list). Have also asked Apple, to which they respond that this is not supported.

Comment: @swiftPunk No difference in scrolling but I used it because of 'Pull to refresh'

Comment: @youjin Ok, thanks. I thought so.