# Why LazyVStack does not Works as Lazy View and it needs ScrollView to works?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have very simple code to testing **Lazy** loading Views, like in the code in down:

***This is my Row:***

```
struct RectangleView: View {
    
    let index: Int
    
    var body: some View {

        print("rendering for: " + String(describing: index))

        return Rectangle()
            .frame(height: 40, alignment: .center)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .overlay(Text(String(index)).bold().foregroundColor(Color.white))

    }
    
}
```

Here is the issue! if you just use `LazyVStack`, SwiftUI will load all the rows until last upper Range of `ForEach` which I do not understand this behavior! because this is `LazyVStack` **Not** `VStack` and I expect that `LazyVStack` take some consideration of laziness and not just rendering from down Range to upper Range!  How ever if I just add a `ScrollView` to the codes! `LazyVStack` start working as a Lazy View, and it stops rendering Views of `ForEach` from down Range to upper Range!

So the question is here why `LazyVStack` needs ScrollView for working as a Lazy View?

I am working on a `CustomScrollView` and I should give Lazy Contents for my `CustomScrollView` and I need LazyVStack for this job, So as I said before LazyVStack works with `ScrollView` and since I am working on a `CustomScrollView` then I am not using Apple `ScrollView`, in this case `LazyVStack` acts like a normal `VStack` and start rendering from down Range to upper Range! Why `LazyVStack` is acting like this? If I do not use `LazyVStack` the memory usage goes upper than 100 mb and with more advanced Row it reach easy over 200 mb and it is so laggy and unusable!

**How can I be sure that, I am passing Lazy Content?**

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var maxRange: Int = 2_000

    var body: some View {

        ScrollView { // Here: If you do not use ScrollView, LazyVStack would works as VStack!!! Why?
            
            LazyVStack {

                ForEach(0...maxRange, id: \.self) { index in RectangleView(index: index) }
                
            }
            .padding()
            
        }

    }
    
}
```

---

***This is my CustomScrollView:***

```
struct CustomScrollView<ViewType: View>: View {

    let importedContent: () -> ViewType

    var body: some View { return importedContent() }

}
```

---

**Use case:**

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var maxRange: Int = 2_000

    var body: some View {

        CustomScrollView { // Here: LazyVStack would works as VStack!!! Why?
            
            LazyVStack {

                ForEach(0...maxRange, id: \.self) { index in RectangleView(index: index) }
                
            }
            .padding()
            
        }

    }
    
}
```

Comment: What does your CustomScrollView do?

Comment: It is just a Custom ScrollView, it will work as a normal ScrollView like we get from Apple. But the issue is not my CustomScrollView, as you see in code i am doing nothing on imported content, the imported content needs be lazy in massive data Range like in code (over 1000). The first step is making our input content be lazy, it does not matter if we use Apple ScrollView or our Custom made ScrollView, And I am working on a part that makes input content be lazy, but as u see LazyVStack does not work, it act like a normal VStack, and  my CustomScrollView or even Apple ScrollView cannot work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65726652/lazyvstack-not-lazy-if-not-within-a-scrollview-or-list  this question has been asked before. I think if you do not use ScrollView, all of the subviews are renedered and their geometries are calculated because LazyStack does not know when they become visible (When subviews are in view).  It is hard to know how Lazy Stacks work under the hood. I also think if it requires ScrollView, why apple didn't use one view for both.

Comment: exactly! after all my working on developing my custom scrollview, i am standing in this point that without making my input content be lazy, it has no fun to use because of heavy lag and memory issue, so i need to make it in some way lazy! in other word should i start on working on CustomLazyVstack?

Comment: I do not understand why you are using CustomScrolView if it is a works as a normal ScrollView. If you explain its functionality, someone might help you find a solution.

Comment: the Current ScrollView from Apple has lots of issue one biggest issue is with drag gestures, I do not want explain all the issues that I have with it, but we do not have access to gestures of ScrollView and that is big issue for me.