# Can I create a ScrollView that is infinite scrolling but has fixed values?

Tags: swiftui

Given a ScrollView like the following
If I have a ScrollView like the one below, can I display 1 to 10 again after the CircleView of 1 to 10?

I want to use the same 1-10 values and display 1, 2, 3....10 after 10. I want to use the same 1...10 values and display 1, 2, 3...10 after 10.

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Divider()
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(0..<10) { index in
                    CircleView(label: "\(index)")
                }
            }.padding()
        }.frame(height: 100)
        Divider()
        Spacer()
    }
}
}

struct CircleView: View {
@State var label: String

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.yellow)
            .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
        Text(label)
    }
  }
}
```

reference:
https://www.simpleswiftguide.com/how-to-create-horizontal-scroll-view-in-swiftui/

Answer (score 7):

This can be done like illustrated in the [Advanced ScrollView Techniques](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/104/) video by Apple. Although that video is from before the SwiftUI era, you can easily implement it in SwiftUI. The advantage of this technique (compared to *Toto Minai*'s answer) is that it does not need to allocate extra memory when scrolling up or down (And you will not run out of memory when you scroll too far ).

[Here](https://github.com/Dev1an/SwiftUI-InfiniteScroll) is an implementation in SwiftUI.

```swift
import SwiftUI
let overlap = CGFloat(100)
struct InfiniteScrollView<Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable {
    let content: Content

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> InfiniteScrollViewRenderer {
        let contentWidth = CGFloat(100)
        let tiledContent = content
                            .float(above: content) // For an implementation of these modifiers:
                            .float(below: content) // see https://github.com/Dev1an/SwiftUI-InfiniteScroll
        let contentController = UIHostingController(rootView: tiledContent)
        let contentView = contentController.view!
        contentView.frame.size.height = contentView.intrinsicContentSize.height
        contentView.frame.size.width = contentWidth
        contentView.frame.origin.y = overlap

        let scrollview = InfiniteScrollViewRenderer()
        scrollview.addSubview(contentView)
        scrollview.contentSize.height = contentView.intrinsicContentSize.height * 2
        scrollview.contentSize.width = contentWidth

        scrollview.contentOffset.y = overlap

        return scrollview
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: InfiniteScrollViewRenderer, context: Context) {}
}

class InfiniteScrollViewRenderer: UIScrollView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let halfSize = contentSize.height / 2

        if contentOffset.y < overlap {
            contentOffset.y += halfSize
        } else if contentOffset.y > halfSize + overlap {
            contentOffset.y -= halfSize
        }
    }
}
```

The main idea is to

- **Tile** the static content. This is done using the `float()` modifiers.
- **Change the offset** of the scrollview to replace the current view with a previous or next tile when you reach a bound. This is done in `layoutSubviews` of the `InfiniteScrollViewRenderer`

### Drawback

The main drawback of this technique is that up until now (July 2021) [Lazy Stacks don't appear to be rendered lazily when they are not inside a SwiftUI List or ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65726652/lazyvstack-not-lazy-if-not-within-a-scrollview-or-list).

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you. I'll have a look at the sample code too.

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it as answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `LazyHStack` to add a new item when the former item appeared:

```swift
// Use `class`, since you don't want to make a copy for each new item
class Item {
    var value: Int
    // Other properties
    
    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

struct ItemWrapped: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    
    var wrapped: Item
}

struct ContentView: View {
    static let itemRaw = (0..<10).map { Item(value: $0) }
    
    @State private var items = [ItemWrapped(wrapped: itemRaw.first!)]
    @State private var index = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Divider()
            // Scroll indicator might be meaningless?
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyHStack(spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        CircleView(label: item.wrapped.value.formatted())
                            .onAppear {
                                // Index iteration
                                index = (index + 1) % ContentView.itemRaw.count
                                
                                items.append(
                                    ItemWrapped(wrapped: ContentView.itemRaw[index]))
                            }
                    }
                }.padding()
            }.frame(height: 100)
            Divider()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I also make it possible to move back from the start point?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in SwiftUI but it doesn’t use a ScrollView. Try this View available here: https://gist.github.com/kevinbhayes/550e4b080d2761aa20d351ff01bab13e

Comment: Just pasting a link to a view is not very helpful, in the future that link may not work, please provide more code and a explanation