Why is `onAppear` called for all elements in a `LazyVStack` or `LazyHStack` if it's not inside a `ScrollView`?
I want to create a LazyHStack without a ScrollView so that I can use my own gestures etc.
What does having a ScrollView do to a LazyVStack so that only the visible elements have onAppear called on them?
struct LazyTestView: View {
  @State var nonScrollViewAppears = 0
  @State var scrollViewAppears = 0
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Non-ScrollView - Views appeared: \(nonScrollViewAppears)")
      ZStack {
        LazyHStack(spacing:0) {
          ForEach(0..<100, id: \.self) { index in
            Rectangle().fill(.orange).frame(width: 100, height: 100)
              .border(.black)
              .overlay(Text("\(index)"))
              .onAppear {
                nonScrollViewAppears += 1
              }
              .onTapGesture {
                print("tapped: \(index)")
              }
          }
        }
        .frame(width: 100, alignment: .leading)
        .border(.red)
      }
      .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
      .contentShape(Rectangle()) // Blocks hit testing
      .clipped() // Clips the view
      .border(.blue)

      Divider()

      Text("ScrollView - Views appeared: \(scrollViewAppears)")
      ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        LazyHStack(spacing:0) {
          ForEach(0..<100, id: \.self) { index in
            Rectangle().fill(.orange).frame(width: 100, height: 100)
              .border(.black)
              .overlay(Text("\(index)"))
              .onAppear {
                scrollViewAppears += 1
              }
          }
        }
        .frame(width: 100*100, height: 150, alignment: .leading)
        .border(.red)
      } // ScrollView
      .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
      .border(.blue)
    }
  }
}


I've added contentShape(Rectangle()) which blocks the hit testing and clipped() which blocks the rendering of the elements outside the ZStack. I've also tested this on a device.
I'm not sure why it's working like this.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/65726652/5133585 ScrollView does some SwiftUI internal magic to lazy stacks/grids.
